# Move objects from a unique_ptr array to a vector

Tags: c++11, stl, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

First I create a unique_ptr array of Foo objects.
And then I move the objects to a vector as shown in the code below.
But this code does not compile.
Another question is since the objects were allocated using the array version of the new operator.
What happens if an exception occurs and the program has to terminate early before I move back the objects to the unique_ptr array? 
In such a situation, the vector vec will destroy its contents using the delete operator, not the array version of the delete operator ?
How do we solve this kind of problem?

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int id;

  Foo(){};
};

int main()
{
  int n = 10;

  std::unique_ptr<Foo []> fooarr(new Foo[n]);

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec;

  for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ){
    fooarr[i].id = i;
  }

  for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ){
    vec.push_back( std::move(fooarr[i]) );
  }

  //then move back the Foo objects from vec to fooarr

}
```

Here is what I got from the compiler.

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:47: error: no
>   matching function for call to 'std::vector >, std::allocator > > >::push_back(Foo)'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:733:
>   note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const
>   _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr >, _Alloc = std::allocator > >] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:746:
>   note:                 void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(_Tp&&)
>   [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr >, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator > >]

Comment: @TartanLlama The first thing is that I don't understand the error. Do you?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It means that you can't `push_back` a `Foo` when a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` is expected.

Comment: @TartanLlama after properly paying attention to the dcalaration, after you other comment, the error makes utter sense ;-).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` then you'll need to dynamically allocate a new `Foo` for each element of the array:

```
for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ){
  vec.push_back( std::make_unique<Foo>(std::move(fooarr[i])) );
}
```

Comment: Why? He could also move one unique_ptr  into each element, which is what he's trying to do, or couldn't he? If not, why not?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The original structure is a `std::unique_ptr` to a single block of `Foo`s allocated with `new[]` and deallocated with `delete[]`. The structure OP wants to change to is a collection of `N` `std::unique_ptr`s to `Foo`s. These are completely different things.

Comment: Ah! Yes, now I see it, thanks. Do you think that misunderstanding (i.e. a mistaken definition of Foo) is the OP's problem? (" I created a unique_ptr array of Foo objects" -- why would anybody do that? :-)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Perhaps. Hopefully OP will comment here if they need more clarification.

Comment: @TartanLlama, 
Does this means that vec contains unique_ptr to the existing Foo objects and at the same time the unique_ptr array "fooarr" also still owns the same Foo objects ?

Comment: @cpp_noname No, they are separate `Foo` objects.

Comment: @TartanLlama, so that std::move is not necessary.

Comment: @cpp_noname The `std::move` will move-construct the `Foo` object you dynamically allocate and store in `vec`.

Comment: @TartanLlama,  then shouldn't it be :

vec.push_back( std::move( std::make_unique<Foo>(  fooarr[i] ) ) )

so that std::move transfers ownership of each new Foo object to vec?

Comment: @cpp_noname No, `std::make_unique<T>()` is already an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer said, if you want to put `Foo` into `vec`, you should call `make_unique<Foo>(std::move(fooarr[i]))`, if you want to put them back, you need [release()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release)

```cpp
Below is the complete implementation   
class Foo
{
public:
  int id;
  Foo() {};
};
int main()
{
  int n = 10;
  std::unique_ptr<Foo[]> fooarr(new Foo[n]);
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)fooarr[i].id = i;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) vec.push_back(make_unique<Foo>(std::move(fooarr[i])));  
  //then move back the Foo objects from vec to fooarr
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    fooarr[i] = *vec[i].release();
    assert(vec[i] == nullptr);  
  }
}
```